# Loop through an event array & show on a react calendar

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I created a React calendar component:

[image: calendar img]

I'm trying to loop through an array of events & showcase the event on the corresponding day.

This is the events array:

```
const events = [
  {
    title: 'Today',
    start: new Date()
  }
]
```

This is the code that renders the cells:

```
const Cells = ({currentMonth, events}) => {

  const monthStart = dateFns.startOfMonth(currentMonth);
  const monthEnd = dateFns.endOfMonth(monthStart);
  const startDate = dateFns.startOfWeek(monthStart);
  const endDate = dateFns.endOfWeek(monthEnd);

  const dateFormat = "D";
  const rows = [];

  let days = [];
  let day = startDate;
  let formattedDate = "";



  while (day <= endDate) {

    for (let i = 0; i < 7; i++) {

      formattedDate = dateFns.format(day, dateFormat);

      const event = events.filter((event, i) => dateFns.format(event.start, 'MM/DD/YYYY') ===  dateFns.format(day, 'MM/DD/YYYY'))

       console.log(event)

      days.push(
        <Cell today={dateFns.isSameDay(day, new Date())} key={day}>
          <span>{formattedDate}</span>
          <div>Event</div>
        </Cell>
      );

      day = dateFns.addDays(day, 1);
    }

    rows.push(
      <Row key={day}>
        {days}
      </Row>
    );

    days = [];
  }

  return <DateWrapper>{rows}</DateWrapper>;
}
```

Notice this filter inside the `for` loop:

```
const event = events.filter((event, i) => dateFns.format(event.start,'MM/DD/YYYY') === dateFns.format(day,'MM/DD/YYYY'))

console.log(event)
```

This is the console.log output:
[image: console.log]

With the one array returning the event as planned:

```
[{…}]
0: start: Fri Apr 12 2019 18:43:50 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time) {}
title: "Today"
```

So my question is, what is the proper way of showcasing the event within this part. Replacing the word "Event" with the actual event title:

```
days.push(
 <Cell today={dateFns.isSameDay(day, new Date())} key={day}>
  <span>{formattedDate}</span>
  <div>Event</div>
 </Cell>
);
```

Comment: Reduce the array of events to array of arrays(or possibly to array of objects, with key being the date) according to the date they occur in(if event is split between several days - you might need conditions used). Then sort that array according to what date each subarray correcponds to and then render it with subarrays being  rendered in one `Cell`

Comment: @seethrough do you have an example? I must admit, I'm not great with the reduce function

Comment: @seethrough I kind of got it working with this: const event = events.reduce((a, b) => {
        let _event = dateFns.format(a, 'MM/DD/YYYY') === dateFns.format(b.start, 'MM/DD/YYYY') ? b : null 
        return {day: dateFns.format(a, 'MM/DD/YYYY'), event: _event}
      }, day)

Comment: I got it working when there is only 1 event, but once there is multiple everything messes up. So I am closer...

Answer (score 0):

As I thought initially, it is a bit complicated. I guess you should be doing something like following

```
const eventsArray = events.reduce(
  (a, b) => { 
    (a[dateFns.format(b.start, 'MM/DD/YYYY')] = a[dateFns.format(b.start, 'MM/DD/YYYY')] || []).push(b);
    return a
  }, 
 {})
```

Then you would have events grouped by date. Finally you can map them to `Cell` component

```
let days 
days = Object.keys(eventsArray).map((day, index) =>
    <Cell today={dateFns.isSameDay(day, new Date())} key={day}>
      <span>{day}</span>
      {eventsArray[day].map(event => <div>{event.title}</div>)}
    </Cell>)
);
```